# 12-inch MacBook & Ethernet

Tags: macbook-pro, network, ethernet

I am trying to configure the network on my 12-inch MacBook. I have the following manual:

[image]

But there is no Ethernet in the list.

[image]

I tried to import it from my old computer, but it output the following:

> The "8021x" configurations could not be important because a "8021x" service has not be set up in Network preferences.

Could you help me?

OS Version: 10.11.5

```
 Hardware: Ethernet
  BSD Device Name: en1
  IPv4:
      Configuration Method: DHCP
  IPv6:
      Configuration Method: Automatic
  Proxies:
      Exceptions List: *.local, 169.254/16
      FTP Passive Mode: Yes
  Service Order: 1

VPN-Zugang:

  Type: IPSec
  IPv4:
      Configuration Method: Automatic
  Proxies:
      Exclude Simple Hostnames: 0
      FTP Proxy Enabled: No
      FTP Passive Mode: Yes
      Gopher Proxy Enabled: No
```

Comment: 802.1x is an **Authentication and Accounting Standard** it is not a profile.  Your MacBook will automatically connect to Ethernet.  Whether your MacBook will the ***authorized*** to connect to services on Ethernet will be a different story.  There's a lot of information that's missing from this question.

Comment: Where you are trying to connect to, why you believe you need a 802.1x configuration file to connect, what happens when you connect your Ethernet cable, what you are expecting to be the result, etc.  Remember, we are not there to see what's happening on your end so we don't even know what questions to ask until we get a clearer picture.

Comment: I also suggest you take the [Tour](http://apple.stackexchange.com/tour) and familiarize yourself with our Help Section - [How to Ask](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/asking)

Comment: Try this command:  `system_profiler SPNetworkDataType | grep "Hardware: Ethernet" -A20` and just post the output.

Comment: Ok...now that I see the info in your original question, your MacBook doesn't have an Ethernet connection.  You need a [USB to Gigabit Adapter](https://goo.gl/U6eunp)  Once you have that, you can plug in your adapter.

Comment: @Allan I already have one: https://ebay.com/itm/401049965802

Comment: When you plug the cable in, does the light come on (on the adapter)?  Issue this command `ifconfig en1` and paste the output

Comment: @Allan I got this, The problem was with the adapter. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The 12-inch MacBook doesn't have an Ethernet port. It is normal for it to not give you an option for something that it doesn't have.

If you can't use WiFi, you will need a USB-C to Ethernet adaptor, as [noted by Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204651).

Comment: I have it. And when I am trying to connect it I still don't see it. So, my question basically was wether it possible to add it and if not then what can I do?

Comment: This sounds like it might be some sort of driver issue with the particular adapter you are using. Which adapter is it?

Comment: I just got one and options look severely limited. Apple specs don't list ethernet as a feature of the USB Expansion.    https://support.apple.com/kb/SP757?locale=en_US